# jquery repeat click/tap event when user clicks and holds

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile, but the page is supposed to work on desktop PCs also, with completely different look and feel. So, depending on screen size I dynamically load the jquery mobile framework. This works well, but the problem now is I need a image to keep rotating as long as one of four available buttons are held down. On a normal desktop PC I can simulate this behavior using `mousedown mouseup/mouseout` combined with a setInterval but this won't work on touch devices, so I tried to add in `vmousedown` event....now the problem is, when JQM is not loaded, only `mousedown` is triggered, however if it is there, the event fires for both.

Sample code:

```
$('#test_btn').on(`mousedown vmousedown`,function(e){
    console.log('clicked'); 
});
```

One solution I can think of is to check whether I am using JQM and have two copies of same code for both events separately....but that seems a bit hacky solution. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: Have you tried `taphold` instead of `mousedown`? http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html

Comment: Just bind the events after jqmobile has loaded?

Comment: @Ejay I am not always loading JQM, that is, when it's in desktop mode.

Omar: I can't use that because taphold fires a delayed event, doesn't repeat it, and also, it might conflict with JQM's functions.